# Temporarily stop MathJax while editing a question

Tags: support, mathjax

The automatic preview of MathJax during editing is nice, but may slow down the editing. Is there a way to temporarily stop this automatic preview during editing?

Comment: A quick-and-dirty way is to edit posts in the text editor of your choice. There is an addon "It's all text" that can simplify the procedure.

Comment: robjohn has a [bookmarkable script](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~robjohn/math/mathjax.html) for that, the rendering on/off pair.

Comment: @pjs36 this works great on my Firefox. Thanks!

Comment: Older post (duplicate?): http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8233/math-rendering-on-demand-and-or-offline-message-composing

Comment: I have noticed slow rendering sometimes, but I have not noticed that this slows down my editing. Or more precisely, as far as I can tell it slows down my editing _only_ if I stop typing in order to see how the formats are coming out. When I would be content to type without rendering turned on at all, then I am also content to type without _waiting_ for rendering to occur, and I do not stop typing at those times. I have not observed the extreme "freezes my browser" problem the other linked question seems to indicate.

Comment: I think this is a valid consideration for people with slower computers, and the rest of us with faster computers may not understand.

Comment: [Yes.](https://noscript.net/) ​ ​

Comment: @theREALyumdub My home computer is often quite slow. It can sometimes take quite a while for it to format a complex post correctly. What I have _not_ noticed (much) is that it prevents me from typing additonal text in the input box during the time when the preview pane looks like garbage. I just don't get a useful preview during that time. If the problem is that text is not even accepted in the input box, that would be worth mentioning in the question.

Comment: @DavidK yes, the problem is that the text is not accepted in the input box.

Comment: OK, that is worse than I recall. On the other hand, I find in general if you just want to write a lot of text to put in a Web form, it's better to keep it in a file on your computer anyway until you're ready to paste it to the Web page; and I already have files of not-ready-to-post text for stackexchange on my computer. If there's not going to be a preview, the advantage of editing directly in the input box is greatly reduced, if not entirely reversed (I have better text editors on my computer than the SE page provides).